# How to set fstab to be able to umount my external HDDs under normal user account?

Tags: mount, fstab, disk, automounting

System: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

Disks in this question are considered external HDDs either `ext4` or `ntfs` formatted.

I am interested in how do I manage to set my `fstab` or whatever else to be able to **Unmount (`umount`) those external HDDs under my normal user account**?

---

I have:

- one External hard disk over USB 3.0 formatted as `ext4`
- one External hard disk over USB 2.0 formatted as `ntfs`

---

Relevant parts of my `fstab`:

```
UUID=<the UUID of the Ext4 disk drive>    /mnt/external-hdd-2tb-usb3-ext4      ext4    nosuid,nodev,nofail    0    0
UUID=<the UUID of the NTFS disk drive>    /mnt/external-hdd-500gb-usb2-ntfs    ntfs    nosuid,nodev,nofail    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `users` option to your `fstab` entries.

---

Working example on my setup:

```
UUID=<the UUID of the Ext4 disk drive>    /mnt/external-hdd-2tb-usb3-ext4      ext4    nosuid,nodev,nofail,users    0    0
UUID=<the UUID of the NTFS disk drive>    /mnt/external-hdd-500gb-usb2-ntfs    ntfs    nosuid,nodev,nofail,users    0    0
```

---

This will allow you (upon reboot) to execute for example:

```
umount /dev/sdX1
```

as an ordinary user without `sudo`.

---

Additionally, on Linux Mint, there is a Disks GUI, where you can then even power off those drives, I stress: once you unmounted them!, by pressing the *Power off this disk* button in the top bar, on the right:

[image: Power off this disk - Linux Mint]